# Will any device work with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio on Mac. Since I am having some issues with the AVD emulator, I am thinking of buying a cheap device ( tablet) and use it for testing purposes. Do I have to make sure the device meets certain specs in order to connect with Android Studio on my mac? I am thinking of getting a cheap tablets like Insigna or Samsung Galaxy E Lite.

Comment: I think specs needed the target audience is more important. For example: do you use a lot of animations I would not use a 'slow' device.

Comment: Any android mobile or tablet can connect to android studio.

Comment: @Rvdk Any suggestions for a cheap device? ( Yeah I agree, slowness is more frustrating than spending more)

Comment: I've heard people recommend using a slower device because if it runs well on a slower device it will almost always run well on a faster one, but the inverse is not necessarily true. Ex. I was developing my most recent app on a pixel and everything was running really smoothly, but then I went to test on a slightly older phone (LG G3) and I noticed some stutter which lead me to realize I was doing too much work on the main thread. If I had only used the pixel I might not have noticed. Theres definitely a limit to how slow though and it really depends on who you choose to target.

Answer (score 1):

There are many affordable android phones nowadays that are almost at par with high end phones. Samsung have lite versions of their phone. Personally I would go for phones with high RAM. I'm using ASUS Zenfone 2 which has 4 GB of RAM. You won't need much storage so you can get the lowest available < 32 GB. Also get a good USB cable.

Comment: Yup - there are tons of cheap prepaid Android phones with decent enough specs. I'm sure the same goes for tablets if that's a preference (but I don't know as much about them). And Black Friday is coming up - it should be easy to find a bargain then.

Answer (score 0):

Any is broader term, you can buy any android device but I would recommend to buy a newer device which has latest android os version and has faster processor so when you connect it to android studio it doesn’t get slow or freeze.